# Stripe warning - Unrecognized token creation parameter

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm just starting with stripe, and I noticed I get a warning in chrome saying:

> Unrecognized token creation parameter parameter: company is not a
>   recognized parameter. This may cause issues with your integration in
>   the future.

This is the code.

```
 stripe.createToken("account", {
        company: {
          name: "bbb",
          address: {
            line1: "77",
            city: "abc",
            state: "aa",
            postal_code: "e2e"
          }
        },
        tos_shown_and_accepted: true
      }).then(function(result) {
        debugger;
         console.log(result);
      });
```

I'm pretty much following the docs here  (step 2)

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens

It creates a token OK though.

The docs in the API reference suggest `company` is an object it should know:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_account

Comment: Hi @raklos, the link you've cited is for frontend integration using stripe.js. To create tokens using stripe-node to call API directly, you will need to call this API at https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_account.

Comment: @wsw I want to create the token client side, so that i can send it to my server, rather than send any personal information to my server

Comment: @raklos - would you perhaps be needing to add in : business_type: 'company' ?

Answer (score -2):

It basically tells you what is wrong.

It says that `company` is not a parameter that is recognized by that stripe endpoint. It creates the token, but ignores your passed parameter

Comment: if you see the link to the documentation i sent, it shows the same similar code (step 2 on that page)

Comment: raklos : I think you're right, and this was a Stripe bug. But I've just tried it now and it worked.